# A csv file has two column CATEGORY and MILES, I have to find % of Miles under Business Category and % of Miles under Personal Category, in python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, sorting, jupyter-notebook, percentage

```
CATEGORY MILES
Business  5.1
Business  4.6
Business  3.9
Personal  8.5
Business  3.7
Personal  6.2
Personal  11
```

This is an excerpt from the excel sheet

Comment: Please provide sample code what you already tried.

Comment: So you are reading from an excel sheet or a csv file?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a text file in CSV format, and you need to read it, convert it into combinations of [Category, Miles], and you want for every Category "% of miles", whatever that may be.

```
Category Miles
   X       1
   X       4
   X       2
   Y       3
```

I think that you want: "Category X has 70% of the miles, Category Y also has 30% of the miles".

To solve this, it is best to cut your problem into smaller pieces.

- Given a string fileName, read the file as text
- Given a string in CSV format, convert it into a sequence of class BusinessMiles
- Given a sequence of BusinessMiles, convert it to "% of miles", according to the definition above.

Cutting your problem into smaller pieces has several advantages:

- The function of each piece will be easier to understand
- Easier to unit test.
- Easier to change, for instance if you don't read from a CSV file, but from a database, or if you don't read from a CSV string, but from an XML or JSON file.
- Most important: you will be able to reuse the pieces for other tasks, like: "How many of my rows are about Business?"

The reusability is demonstrated most clearly, because several of these pieces already exist and can be used freely: reading the file and converting the file to CSV.

For this, consider to use [Nuget Package CSV helper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/). Easy to use, versatile, and thus one of the most used CSV packages.

So let's assume you have procedures to read the CSV file and to convert it to a sequence of BusinessMiles

```
enum Category
{
    Business,
    Personal,
}

class BusinessMile          // TODO: invent proper name
{
    public Category Category {get; set;}
    public Decimal Miles {get; set;}
}
```

By using an enum you can be certain that after reading the CSV there won't be any incorrect Categories. It will be easy to add new Categories for a future version. If you don't know at compile time which Categories are allowed, consider to use a string for it. This has the danger that someone might have a typing error, which leads to a complete new Category, without anyone noticing "Personnel" instead of "Personal"

```
IEnumerable<BusinessMile> ReadBusinessMiles(string csvText)
{
    // use CSVHelper to convert the csvText to the sequence
}

IEnumerable<BusinessMile> ReadBusineMilesFile(string fileName)
{
    // either use CSVHelper, or read the file and call the other method
}
```

After this, your problem will be easy:

```
string fileName = ...
IEnumerable<BusinessMile> businessMiles = ReadBusinesMilesFile(fileName);
```

Make groups of BusinessMiles that have the same Category:

```
var categoryGroups = businessMiles.GroupBy(
    businessMile => businessMile.Category,

    // parameter resultSelector: for every Category, and all BusinessMiles
    // that have this Category to make one new
    (category, businessMilesInThisCategory) => new
    {
        Category = category,
        TotalMiles = businesMilesInThisCategory
            .Select(businessMile => businessMile.Miles)
            .Sum(),
    });
```

So now you've got:

```
Category TotalMiles
   X         7
   Y         3
```

If you really want to have percentages, you need to get the total of all Miles of all Categories (=6), and divide TotalMiles by this total

```
var totalMiles = categorieGroups.Select(group => group.TotalMiles).Sum();

var result = categoryGroups.Select(group => new
{
    Category = group.Category,
    TotalMilesPercentage = 100.0M * group.TotalMiles / totalMiles,
})
```

In my definition of BusinessMiles, the Miles are a decimal. Take care to convert it if your Miles are integers.